# Provisioning profile stored in XCode project file for iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5, provisioning-profile

I thought I'd figured out how to store XCode projects in source control - I only version the .pbxproject file and this seems to work great.

But then I noticed the provisioning profile is also kept there. This doesn't seem very good, I'm working remotely with another developer and we both have individual provisioning profiles. We keep committing new versions of the .pbxproject file with our own profile every time we change anything which is annoying, and I wonder if sharing such information is a security risk?

Is there a way around this? Are we 'supposed' to be using the same team profile or something like that, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the profile selector to "Automatic" in the Build Settings and this problem will stop.

Comment: Will that automatically choose between development and distribution provisioning profiles depending on build type?

Comment: You set the signing identity for each scheme, so if you have Debug and Release schemes and you set them both to Automatic, it will do what you want.

Comment: I don't have any "Automatic" option for Provisioning Profile field.... How should I proceed?

Comment: @Sr.Richie first, go into the "General" tab of the app target. Make sure there is a Team chosen under the Identity section. Now click the Build Settings tab and type "code sign" in the search box. The Debug & Release schemes will have separate rows. Click the popup under your app's name in each row. The popup menu should be in two sections: Automatic and Identities In Keychain. Just pick iOS Developer from Automatic and you should be good to go.